# Conditionally render part of object onClick inside a map (REACT.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

I am trying to conditionally render part of an object (user comment) onClick of button.

The objects are being pulled from a Firebase Database.

I have multiple objects and want to only render comments for the Result component I click on.

The user comment is stored in the same object as all the other information such as name, date and ratings.

My original approach was to set a boolean value of false to each Result component and try to change this value to false but cannot seem to get it working.

Code and images attached below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
accumRating: 3.7
adheranceRating: 4
cleanRating: 2
date: "2020-10-10"
place: "PYGMALIAN"
staffRating: 5
timestamp: t {seconds: 1603315308, nanoseconds: 772000000}
userComment: "Bad"
viewComment: false
}
```

```
    const results = props.data.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <div className='Results' key={index}>
                <span>{item.place}</span>
                <span>{item.date}</span>
                <Rating
                    name={'read-only'}
                    value={item.accumRating}
                    style={{
                        width: 'auto',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                />

                <button>i</button>
                {/* <span>{item.userComment}</span> */}

            </div >
        )
    })
```

[image: Snapshot of interface]

Comment: Did you try using the short-circuit operator ?
`{item.viewComment && <span>{item.userComment}</span>}`

Comment: Do you want toggle button to show comments? and viewComment is coming from firebase or you are setting it manually?

Comment: @Rohitha yes essentially I want a toggle button to view more info (comments) and display the comments below the name, date and rating. THe viewComment is coming from Firebase. Maybe I should change this?

Comment: No, you can set the state based on viewComment and render it.

Comment: @Rohitha I don't fully follow. I'm having trouble changing viewComment to true.

Comment: When you want viewComment to be true? on click of i button?

Comment: @Rohitha yeah exactly

Comment: Check this, i created a small demo. https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-bell-nsgsw

Answer (score 0):

You have to track individual state of each button toggle in that case.

The solution I think of is not the best but you could create a click handler for the button and adding a classname for the `span` then check if that class exists. If it exists then, just hide the comment.
Just make sure that the next sibling of the button is the target you want to hide/show

```
const toggleComment = (e) => {
  const sibling =  e.target.nextElementSibling;
  sibling.classList.toggle('is-visible');
  
  if (sibling.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
    sibling.style.display = 'none'; // or set visibility to hidden
  } else {
    sibling.style.display = 'inline-block'; // or set visibility to visible
  }
}
```

```
<button onClick={toggleComment}>i</button>
<span>{item.userComment}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
const [backendData, setBackendData] = useState([]);

...

const showCommentsHandler = (viewComment, index) => {
      let clonedBackendData = [...this.state.backendData];
      clonedBackendData[index].viewComment = !viewComment;

      setBackendData(clonedBackendData);

    }

....
return(
   <div>
    ....
    <button onClick={() => showCommentsHandler(item.viewComment, index)}>i</button>
    {item.viewComment && item.userComment}
  <div>
```

Comment: Should I be putting the first two parts in my app.js file? Or everything in Results.js

Comment: Hope you are fetching data from firebase in Results.js. If not then first two parts should be put in the component where you are fetching then pass showCommentsHandler in props.

Answer (score 0):

You can store an array with that `place`s which are clicked, for example:

```js
const [ selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = React.useState([]);

const onClick = (el) => {
   if (selectedItems.includes(el.place)) {
     setSelectedItems(selectedItems.filter(e => e.place !== el.place));
   } else {
     setSelectedItems(selectedItems.concat(el));
   }
}
```

and in your render function

```js
const results = props.data.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <div className='Results' key={index}>
                <span>{item.place}</span>
                <span>{item.date}</span>
                <Rating
                    name={'read-only'}
                    value={item.accumRating}
                    style={{
                        width: 'auto',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                />

                <button onClick={() => onClick(item)}>i</button>
{ /* HERE */ }
                { selectedItems.includes(item.place) && <span>{item.userComment}</span> }

            </div >
        )
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useState` or your component won't update even if you change the property from false to true.

In order to do so you need an id since you might have more than one post.
(Actually you have a timestamp already, you can use that instead of an id.)

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      accumRating: 3.7,
      adheranceRating: 4,
      cleanRating: 2,
      date: "2020-10-10",
      place: "PYGMALIAN",
      staffRating: 5,
      timestamp: { seconds: 1603315308, nanoseconds: 772000000 },
      userComment: "Bad",
      viewComment: false
    }
  ]);
```

Create a function that updates the single property and then updates the state.

```
const handleClick = (id) => {
    const singlePost = posts.findIndex((post) => post.id === id);
    const newPosts = [...posts];
    newPosts[singlePost] = {
      ...newPosts[singlePost],
      viewComment: !newPosts[singlePost].viewComment
    };
    setPosts(newPosts);
  };
```

Then you can conditionally render the comment.

```
return (
      <div className="Results" key={index}>
        <span>{item.place}</span>
        <span>{item.date}</span>
        <Rating
          name={"read-only"}
          value={item.accumRating}
          style={{
            width: "auto",
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
        />

        <button onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}>i</button>
        {item.viewComment && <span>{item.userComment}</span>}
      </div>
    );
```

Check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-feistel-44zzf?file=/src/App.js) to see how it works.